# Angular 4 router is appending components on routerLink navigation instead of destroying them

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, routerlink

When navigating from within a submodule from a child route to another sibling child route, instead of the router destroying the previous component, it appends the new one on navigation forward and backward.

Why is this happening?

Starting in `/#/subscriber/lookup`, moving to `/#/subscriber/register` route

```
<a [routerLink]="['../register']">Subscriber register link</a>
```

app.routes.ts

```
/**
 * Angular 2 decorators and services
 */

import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

/**
 * Other services
 */
import { RouteProtection } from '../services/route-protection.service';
// import { DataResolver } from './app.resolver';

/**
 * Imported Components
 */
import { LoginComponent } from '../login/login.component';
import { NotFound404Component } from '../404/notfound404.component';

export const ROUTES: Routes = [{
   path: '',
   redirectTo: 'subscriber',
   pathMatch: 'full',
}, {
   path: 'subscriber',
   loadChildren: '../+subscriber/subscriber.module#SubscriberModule',
   // canActivate: [RouteProtection]
}, {
   path: 'detail',
   loadChildren: '../+detail/detail.module#DetailModule',
   canActivate: [RouteProtection]
}, {
   path: 'login',
   component: LoginComponent
}, {
   path: '**',
   component: NotFound404Component
}, {
   path: '404',
   component: NotFound404Component
}];

// export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true});
```

subscriber.routes.ts

```
/**
 * Imported Components
 */
import { SubscriberLookupComponent } from './lookup/subscriber-lookup.component';
import { SubscriberRegisterComponent } from './register/subscriber-register.component';

/*
 * Shared Utilities & Other Services
 */
// import { RouteProtection } from '../services/route-protection.service';
// import { DataResolver } from '../services/app.resolver';

export const subscriberRoutes = [{
   path: '',
   children: [{
      path: '',
      pathMatch: 'full',
      redirectTo: 'lookup'
   }, {
      path: 'lookup',
      component: SubscriberLookupComponent, //canActivate: [RouteProtection],
   }, {
      path: 'register',
      component: SubscriberRegisterComponent, //canActivate: [RouteProtection],  // resolve: {      'dataBroughtToComponent': DataResolver   }
   }]

},];
```

app.module.ts

```
/**
 * `AppModule` is the main entry point into Angular2's bootstraping process
 */
@NgModule({
   bootstrap: [AppComponent],
   declarations: [ // declarations contains: components, directives and pipes

      // Components
      AppComponent, LoginComponent, NotFound404Component, // Directives
      NavSidebarComponent, NavHeaderComponent, NavFooterComponent

      // Pipes

   ],
   imports: [ // import other modules
      BrowserModule, SharedModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, {useHash: true}), NgbModule.forRoot()
      /*      ApplicationInsightsModule.forRoot({
               instrumentationKey: '116b16e7-0307-4d62-b201-db3ea88a32c7'
            })*/

   ],
   providers: [ // expose our Services and Providers into Angular's dependency injection
      ENV_PROVIDERS, APP_PROVIDERS, AUTH_PROVIDERS]
})
```

subscriber.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [
      SharedModule,
      CommonModule,
      RouterModule.forChild(subscriberRoutes)
   ],
   declarations: [ // Components / Directives / Pipes
      SubscriberLookupComponent,
      SubscriberRegisterComponent
   ],
   // exports: [
   //    SharedModule,
   //    SubscriberLookupComponent,
   //    SubscriberRegisterComponent
   // ]
})
```

This is what happens on navigation:

[image: appending routes]

Comment: can you reproduce using a plunker

Comment: very complicated to reproduce this one file at a time on plunker, i will try

Comment: are you available in teamviewer to debug further?

Comment: let me try to get teamviewer setup through our firewall here

Comment: Alright I got it setup, lets try to connect. is there a private chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152284/discussion-between-tetradev-and-aravind).

Comment: @Aravind i have a lazy loaded module `members` and it has two component `login` and `forgotpassword`, when I am at login page the module is invoked but when i click forgot passwod link the route becomes `/members/login/forgotPassword'` rather than `members/forgotPassword'`. my routerlink on `<a>` tag is like `routerLink="forgotPassword"` what is that I am missing? due to this the console has error `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'members/login/forgotPassword'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having this same issue. I find out that when my new component was created, it throws an exception then my older component was not being destroyed.

In my case, in the template I have `{{model.field}}` and in the TypeScript `model: Model;`, but when the component is created, the `model` was `undefined`. I think if any exception is throwed on the creation of the component, the router can't destroy the older component.

I used the Visual Studio Code debugger to find the exception cause.

So I just putted a `*ngIf` to check model:

```
<tag *ngIf="model">
    {{model.field}}
</tag>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize my component was throwing an error, but you're right. If component A throws an error, then trying to navigate to Component B will prevent A from being destroyed by the router. It must be an angular bug.

Answer (score 2):

At first I thought this was because I was viewing my angular app through **BrowserSync**.

It seemed like for some reason, BrowserSync's javascript messes with angular's router. I'm assuming this is a bug. When I view my app directly, the router works as expected.

However, then it happened again in production without browsersync.

The answer from Caio Filipe fixed it for me. **It was because my component `A` was throwing an error**, so when navigating to Component `B`, Component `A` could not be destroyed due to the error. I [submitted a ticket](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19273) with angular.

Comment: Here another ticket for the same issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19093  the severity has been increased in the meantime and hopefully fixed soon.